# Dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, hp, system-installation

I have an [HP Envy Dv7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Envy#Envy_Dv7) with Windows 8 installed from the factory and recently upgraded to [Windows 8.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1).

I have dual booted Windows and Ubuntu on my last Windows 7 laptop, but now I can´t figure it out. On my last laptop I would power it up, press <kbd>F12</kbd> or something and boot it trough the USB drive, and then install trough the option `Install ubuntu side-by-side Windows` or would just install it on other partition. And it would work just fine.

Now, with Windows 8.1 I don't get that initial boot screen that tells me to press <kbd>F12</kbd> to boot from another device; the computer just starts booting really quick (xD). I have to go to settings and select advanced boot and tell it to boot from USB. And when I get to install Ubuntu it doesn´t show the option to install side-by-side with Windows.

I hear some talk about [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB), but I don´t know what that is.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Comment: In Windows under Power Settings, turn off fast boot.  Then you get more of a chance to type the key (may not be F12 on the new machine) to bring up the efi boot menu, or the key to bring up the BIOS/UEFI Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I was having exactly the same issues and almost bricked my laptop.

I finally found information on this. It turns out Windows 8 & 8.1 have a new mechanism for reaching the [EFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) to select a boot device. Hover your mouse over the right of the screen and choose the very last option "Settings", in its menu the last text option "Change PC Settings", the last option again "Recovery" and then finally "Advanced Startup" which will allow you to choose to boot from USB...

Sources:

1. *[How to access your Advanced Boot Options in Windows 8/8.1](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1877214/access-advanced-boot-options-windows.html)*
2. *[UEFI Firmware Settings - Boot to from inside Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/20256-uefi-firmware-settings-boot-inside-windows-8-a.html)*

Answer (score 0):

Check *[Install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1 in 10 easy steps](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)*. This solution has worked for me.