# Dual Boot Ubuntu on Windows 8.1 tablet

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 14.10

I purchased three windows 8.1 Nextbook tablets on Black Friday. I want to dual boot Ubuntu on my tablet but when I followed the steps from this link, [Dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384745/dual-boot-windows-8-1-and-ubuntu/)

(Or at least the ones from the mentioned links in the article). For some reason my first tablet got bricked, any ideas? I have managed to dual boot Ubuntu on my Android using Linux Installer on the Play store, isn't there a similar app for windows tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a long and dangerous (for my tab) way to install it although it is not dual booting. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto an ssd card and swapped out the prebuilt ssd card for the one with Ubuntu. For some reason the touch screen quit working with Ubuntu though.